# .NET string IndexOf unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, string, indexof

A string variable str contains the following somewhere inside it: `se\">`

I'm trying to find the beginning of it using:

```
str.IndexOf("se\\\">")
```

which returns -1

Why isn't it finding the substring?

Note: due to editing the snippet showed 5x \ for a while, the original had 3 in a row.

Comment: What you are doing looks ok; could you post the actual code? Maybe it's just a small detail...

Comment: I think that you may have one extra backslash - are you sure that it isn't actually `se">` you want to find?

Comment: looking at original question and Kev edition, it seem there is a lot more \ in the indexof, is that an error?

Comment: Answers using Verbatim String literals ( @"se\\">" etc) might help ensure you have the correct amount of back slashes ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is in fact searching for `'se\\">'`. When searching for strings including backslashes I usually find it easier to use verbatim strings:

```
str.IndexOf(@"se\"">")
```

In this case you also have a quote in the search string, so there is still some escaping, but I personally find it easier to read.

**Update**: my answer was based on the edit that introduced extra slashes in the parameter to the `IndexOf` call. Based on current version, I would place my bet on `str` simply not containing the expected character sequence.

**Update 2**:
Based on the comments on this answer, it seems to be some confusion regarding the role of the '\' character in the strings. When you inspect a string in the Visual Studio debugger, it will be displayed with escaping characters.

So, if you have a text box and type 'c:\' in it, inspecting the Text property in the debugger will show 'c:\\'. An extra backslash is added for escaping purposes. The actual string content is still 'c:\' (which can be verified by checking the `Length` property of the string; it will be 3, not 4).

If we take the following string (taken from the comment below)

> " '<em
>   class=\"correct_response\">a
>   night light</em><br
>   /><br /><table
>   width=\"100%\"><tr><td
>   class=\"right\">Ingrid</td></tr></table>')"

...the `\"` sequences are simply escaped quotation marks; the backslashes are not part of the string content. So, you are in fact looking for `'se">'`, not `'se\">'`. Either of these will work:

```
str.IndexOf(@"se"">");  // verbatim string; escape quotation mark by doubling it
str.IndexOf("se\">");   // regular string; escape quotation mark using backslash
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Here's the output from VS 2008 immediate window.
? answer
" '<em class=\"correct_response\">a night light</em><br /><br /><table width=\"100%\"><tr><td class=\"right\">Ingrid</td></tr></table>')"
?  answer.IndexOf(@"se\"">")
-1

Comment: Note that in the 'se\">' sequences that you see, the '\' character is only an escape character for the quotation mark. The string content is actually 'se">' without the backslash. str.IndexOf(@"se"">") should find what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
string str = "<case\\\">";
int i = str.IndexOf("se\\\">"); // i = 3
```

Maybe you're not correctly escaping one of the two strings?

*EDIT* there's an extra couple of `\` in the string you are searching for.

Comment: for me this work too:  string str = "<case\">";  int i = str.IndexOf("se\">");

Comment: doesn't work on this string: " '<em class=\"correct_response\">a night light</em><br /><br /><table width=\"100%\"><tr><td class=\"right\">Ingrid</td></tr></table>')"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the str variable does not actually contain the backslash.
It may be just that when you mouse over the variable while debugging, the debugger tooltip will show the escape character.

e.g. If you put a breakpoint after this assignment

```
string str = "123\"456";
```

the tooltip will show 123\"456 and not 123"456.

However if you click on the visualize icon, you will get the correct string 123"456

Answer (score 1):

Following code:

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    string s = File.ReadAllText (@"D:\txt.txt");
    Console.WriteLine (s);
    int i = s.IndexOf("se\\\">");
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}
```

Gives following output:

```
some text before se\"> some text after
17
```

Seems like working to me...

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("se\"">")
```

seems to work in VB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for   **se\">**

then

```
str.IndexOf(@"se\"">")
```

is less error-prone. Note the double "" and single \

Edit, after the comment: it seems like the string may contain ecaping itself, in which case in    **se\">**  the **\"** was an escaped quote, so the literal text is simply **se">** and the string to use is  `Indexof("se\">")`

Comment: if you look at original question versu Kev edition, you can see where the extra \ come from

Comment: You all may be correct but for some reason, the suggested answers don't work on this string (the outer quotes are not part of the string):
doesn't work on this string: " '<em class=\"correct_response\">a night light</em><br /><br /><table width=\"100%\"><tr><td class=\"right\">Ingrid</td></tr></table>')"

Answer (score 1):

DoubleQuotes within a string need to be specified like `""` Also consider using verbatim strings - So an example would be

```
var source = @"abdefghise\"">jklmon";
Console.WriteLine(source.IndexOf(@"se\"">"));  // returns 8
```